# How can I programmatically find the full path of the main executing class

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I'm trying to local a properties file programmatically without having 
to pass it's fullpathname on the commandline to my program.  I figure if I can 
locate the path of the main class, I can stick my properties file in the same 
directory or a sub-directory.

If that won't work is there some other way I can locate the path of a properties 
file without passing it in on the commandline.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the file is expected to be located relative to the main class, you can use [`Class.getResource()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) as follows:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        URL props = MainClass.class.getResource( "foo.properties" );
        // ...
    }
}
```

These will return a `URL` or an `InputStream`, respectively; there's an overload for [`Properties.load()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)) which accepts an `InputStream`.

You can specify paths in subdirectories, etc. relative to the class' location, or use the `getResource()` method on another class to obtain files relative to that location.

If you want to calculate a path relative to the current working directory (which is not necessarily the same as the parent of the main class), then you can use the following to obtain that path:

```
String cwd = System.getProperty( "user.dir" );
```

There's a list of available system properties in the documentation for [`System.getProperties()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()).

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the ClassLoader to locate the application directory](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/04/java-finding-application-directory.html), but as [Rob says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740999/how-can-i-programmatically-find-the-full-path-of-the-main-executing-class/741011#741011), it would be better to load the properties file from the classpath directly.